# Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'catalog_product_entity_int_tmp_indexer' doesn't exist

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I have upgraded a Magento 2 webshop from 2.3.7 to 2.4.6

The whole system seems to work, except the reindexing process.

When trying to reindex, it gives an error on the Product Flat Data indexation.

Anyone has an idea? I can't figure out why this is a problem.
With the same user/pass i can create a table without any problems.

```
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:02
Product Flat Data index process error during indexation process:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'catalog_product_entity_int_tmp_indexer' doesn't exist, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_int_tmp_indexer` (`entity_id`, `fl_fietsen_frame`, `links_exist`, `links_purchased_separately`, `price_type`, `price_view`, `sku_type`, `tax_class_id`, `visibility`, `weight_type`, `status`) SELECT `et`.`entity_id`, IFNULL(st1.value, t1.value) AS `fl_fietsen_frame`, IFNULL(st2.value, t2.value) AS `links_exist`, IFNULL(st3.value, t3.value) AS `links_purchased_separately`, IFNULL(st4.value, t4.value) AS `price_type`, IFNULL(st5.value, t5.value) AS `price_view`, IFNULL(st6.value, t6.value) AS `sku_type`, IFNULL(st7.value, t7.value) AS `tax_class_id`, IFNULL(st8.value, t8.value) AS `visibility`, IFNULL(st9.value, t9.value) AS `weight_type`, IFNULL(st10.value, t10.value) AS `status` FROM `catalog_product_entity_tmp_indexer` AS `et`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON e.entity_id = et.entity_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t1` ON e.entity_id = t1.entity_id AND t1.attribute_id = 298 AND t1.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `st1` ON e.entity_id = st1.entity_id AND st1.attribute_id = 298 AND st1.store_id = 1
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t2` ON e.entity_id = t2.entity_id AND t2.attribute_id = 126 AND t2.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `st2` ON e.entity_id = st2.entity_id AND st2.attribute_id = 126 AND st2.store_id = 1
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t3` ON e.entity_id = t3.entity_id AND t3.attribute_id = 123 AND t3.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `st3` ON e.entity_id = st3.entity_id AND st3.attribute_id = 123 AND st3.store_id = 1
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t4` ON e.entity_id = t4.entity_id AND t4.attribute_id = 127 AND t4.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `st4` ON e.entity_id = st4.entity_id AND st4.attribute_id = 127 AND st4.store_id = 1
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t5` ON e.entity_id = t5.entity_id AND t5.attribute_id = 130 AND t5.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `st5` ON e.entity_id = st5.entity_id AND st5.attribute_id = 130 AND st5.store_id = 1
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t6` ON e.entity_id = t6.entity_id AND t6.attribute_id = 128 AND t6.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `st6` ON e.entity_id = st6.entity_id AND st6.attribute_id = 128 AND st6.store_id = 1
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t7` ON e.entity_id = t7.entity_id AND t7.attribute_id = 134 AND t7.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `st7` ON e.entity_id = st7.entity_id AND st7.attribute_id = 134 AND st7.store_id = 1
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t8` ON e.entity_id = t8.entity_id AND t8.attribute_id = 99 AND t8.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `st8` ON e.entity_id = st8.entity_id AND st8.attribute_id = 99 AND st8.store_id = 1
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t9` ON e.entity_id = t9.entity_id AND t9.attribute_id = 129 AND t9.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `st9` ON e.entity_id = st9.entity_id AND st9.attribute_id = 129 AND st9.store_id = 1
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t10` ON e.entity_id = t10.entity_id AND t10.attribute_id = 97 AND t10.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `st10` ON e.entity_id = st10.entity_id AND st10.attribute_id = 97 AND st10.store_id = 1 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `entity_id` = VALUES(`entity_id`), `fl_fietsen_frame` = VALUES(`fl_fietsen_frame`), `links_exist` = VALUES(`links_exist`), `links_purchased_separately` = VALUES(`links_purchased_separately`), `price_type` = VALUES(`price_type`), `price_view` = VALUES(`price_view`), `sku_type` = VALUES(`sku_type`), `tax_class_id` = VALUES(`tax_class_id`), `visibility` = VALUES(`visibility`), `weight_type` = VALUES(`weight_type`), `status` = VALUES(`status`)
Category Flat Data index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
```

Tried to find on Google and SO, but it seems noone has ever encountered a problem with the _tmp_indexer table.

UPDATE 1:
It is really only affecting the Flat Product data.
When i disable the flat product catalog, it runs totally fine.

Answer (score 0):

As per following article [Flat catalogs](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/catalog/catalog/catalog-flat.html)

Use of a flat catalog is no longer recommended as a best practice. Continued use of this feature is known to cause performance degradation and other indexing issues. A detailed description and solution is available in the Help Center.

Affected versions include:

- Adobe Commerce on cloud infrastructure, 2.3.x and above
- Adobe Commerce (On-Premise), 2.3.x and above
- Magento Open Source, 2.3.x and above

It will be better if you do not use flat catalog.